# Ruby on Rails - Can't set cookies in some actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, authorization

I'm trying to set in cookies `target_path` that non authorized user tried to reach and after authorization redirect him to the target. Everything works fine and good, but then I tried to set as target `edit_test_path` or `create_test_path` and other methods with POST/PATCH/PUT requests and seems that no cookies are being set. What can be the case?

application.rb - I'm setting cookies here. `authenticate_user!` calling in almost every controller `before_action`s

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  helper_method :current_user,
                :logged_in?

  private

  def authenticate_user!
    unless current_user
      cookies[:target_path] = request.path_info

      redirect_to login_path, alert: 'Verify Email or Password'
    end
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_user.present?
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb - I'm trying to redirect to the target from cookies here

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new; end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

    if user&.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id

      cookies[:target_path] ? (redirect_to cookies[:target_path]) : (redirect_to root_path) # With verb POST cookies don't work
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Verify Email or Password'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def exit
    session[:user_id] = nil

    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think, you can do this with POST/PUT/PATCH requests. When you are doing `redirect_to`, rails sends `302 Found` reponse with `location` specified in parameter of `redirect_to` in your case `cookies[:target_path]` or `root_path`.

Browser then understends it should do redirect and sends GET request to URL specified in `location` header. You cannot nor should try to tell it to do POST/PUT/PATCH requests - these types of requests usually also require some kind of data (eg submitted form) that goes along with the request. You lost all of these data during redirect to login page anyway.

What I am trying to say - use these redirects only for GET requests. It will not work for POST/PUT/PATCH.